# Developing Qt app for Symbian in Indian languages

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, multilingual

I have a S60 5th edition mobile which supports English language only. How to develop an application for it in any other language? Can we install required language pack? Or do we need phones which support required language pack? (Basically I want to develop an application entirely in Tamil language)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop the app in Qt for symbian Platform

then use the Qt linguist to convert all text to tamil language.

See here for more info -

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-programmers.html#tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the link macha (localizing was not the problem though), the problem was in the ttf that I used, it mapped all english characters to tamil n tamil would come as junk! I downloaded a proper unicode tamil font n it worked fine :)

Comment: Now I have another problem, localization of strings doesn't work for Window title and menu softkey texts:(. When I localize it using languages like Arabic/Russian it works (the phone internally supports these languages) but Tamil text still gets displayed as junk! What could be done to these titles and menu texts?